# How to generate Mobx store, json, hive class from single class;

Tags: flutter, dart, code-generation

I am using the code generation to use the Mobx, Hive, and JsonSerializable for a flutter.

So I have a Class I need to define it 3 times to generate all the required classes to work properly.

suppose I have a class:-

```
class A {
    int x
 }
```

I need to define it 3 times.

for JsonSerializable:-

```
@JsonSerializable
 class A {
    int x
 }
```

For Hive:-

```
 @HiveType(0)
  class A {
   @HiveField(0)
    int x
 }
```

for mobx:-

```
class A = _A with _$A;
abstract class _A with Store{
    @observable int x
 }
```

is there any way to create just one class definition and create all the required generated class?

Comment: Try [this](https://medium.com/@papmodern/the-combination-of-hive-and-mobx-generators-8b51780292a9) article for Hive and Mobx generators from a single class.
It worked for me.